# How to get complete memory dump in Windows 10?

Tags: forensics

It is possible to get information like process ID, process type, physical & virtual address from a memory dump in Windows 10?

Comment: It isn't the avenue for this question. You may ask it somewhere in a windows 10 product forum. And plus it doesn't fit to the forensics space.

Comment: Question in title doesn't seem to match the question in the body. Which are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that are able to dump the memory of a windows system by using own drivers to access the memory directly. You can find a list of these tools [here](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging).

You can then analyse the generated image with a memory forensics framework like volatility.

Comment: Link is broken.