# Find a string in the whole RAM

Tags: windows, memory

How to search a string in the whole RAM? (not only in some processes' allocated memory, but the whole RAM)

Or is there a way to dump the whole RAM into a 4GB or 8GB disk file? Then I could easily  do:

```
grep mypassword c:\ramdump.raw
```

Usage example: I'd like to know if a password manager **stores my master password in plaintext**, as [found by a security team here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/critical-vulnerabilities-uncovered-in-popular-password-managers/).

I'm using Windows 7 x64, as administrator.

---

Note: Unlike [How to get complete memory dump in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1023640/how-to-get-complete-memory-dump-in-windows-10) I specifically want to search content in the RAM, and not get information *from* a memory dump. Moreover this question is unclear: the title doesn't match the content ("Question in title doesn't seem to match the question in the body.")

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1023640/how-to-get-complete-memory-dump-in-windows-10

Comment: @Mokubai No it's a bit different, here I specifically want to search content in the RAM. Moreover this question has a poor wording ("Question in title doesn't seem to match the question in the body. Which are you asking?").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get complete memory dump in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1023640/how-to-get-complete-memory-dump-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Azevedo  No it's a bit different, here I specifically want to search content in the RAM. Moreover this question has a poor wording ("Question in title doesn't seem to match the question in the body. Which are you asking?")

Answer (score 3):

Here are possible ways to create full memory dumps:

https://support.avast.com/en-eu/article/Windows-complete-memory-dump

https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4641/~/collecting-a-full-memory-dump-in-windows-10

The method is to add this to registry:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl]
"CrashDumpEnabled"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\kbdhid\Parameters]
"CrashOnCtrlScroll"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\i8042prt\Parameters]
"CrashOnCtrlScroll"=dword:00000001
```

and then to generate a crash:

> Manually force a Windows crash by holding down the CTRL key on the right side of your keyboard and pressing the Scroll Lock key twice (right CTRL + 2x Scroll Lock).

I'll try then to search in the dump file with a HEX editor.

Comment: To the downvoter, please can you explain how to improve this answer? Or what is wrong? (I found this technique after posting my original question, after further research)

Answer (score 2):

#### How to I find a string anywhere in RAM?

You can use `windbg` ([Download Debugging Tools for Windows - WinDbg - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools)) for this.

Example:

> To search for a string (`Error: 1002`) in memory, we run the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> 0:000> s -a 0 L?80000000 "Error: 1002"
> 04b0e06c  45 72 72 6f 72 3a 20 31-30 30 32 00 00 00 00 00  Error: 1002.....
> ```
>
> ...
>
> [image]

Source [WinDbg: search for a string – Distributed Services: Notes from the field](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2012/02/21/windbg-search-for-a-string/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [s (Search Memory) - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/s--search-memory-)

Comment: @Basj See [Getting Started with WinDbg (User-Mode) - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg)

Comment: The commands go in the text box (console) at the bottom, to the right of the prompt `0:000> `

Comment: The program you are going to debug is your password manager (not notepad as in the getting started example)

Comment: You can still search the whole ram. You just need to open a program to get access to the console.

Comment: I tried, but it only search in the RAM *attached to the specific program*... Thus you cannot search in the whole RAM for all programs.

Comment: *The program you are going to debug is your password manager (not notepad as in the getting started example)*: if windbg.exe searches in the whole RAM as you said, we could attach it to notepad.exe and then search *everywhere* in my 8GB of RAM? (no matter which programs owns specific parts of it)

Comment: @Basj You can't search some other programs RAM, but you can't write to it either. So if the password is in plain text it must be in the RAM belonging to the password manager.

Comment: Yes @DavidPostill there are lots of situation for which it's interesting to read in the global RAM: example: if the process has terminated 2 hours ago, I'd like to see if it is still in the RAM. Obviously I cannot attach `windbg` to a terminated program, etc.

Comment: @Basj Then you need to configure Windows to produce a full memory dump when a program crashes - you already know how to do this. Post mortem debugging is different to run time debugging.

Comment: Note that is the OS kernel code that produces the full dump as it has extra privileges that users (even system or admin) don't. You as a user (even admin) cannot just dump all memory

Comment: I just found in the meantime indeed, I'll try if it works :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use an **Hex editor**. Most Hex editors are developed to handle huge files. They can search for either strings or hex sequences.

Some hex editors can also dump the content of RAM, read entire RAW disks or dump them, it depends on the editor.

**Have in mind that some RAM areas won't be accessible for obvious security reasons. So if you are trying to hack some password from RAM you probably won't get it. Life is not that easy.**

This method is usually used to debug, not to hack.

[image]

Comment: Yes I'll use a HEX editor or `grep`  but first I need to have a file containing the whole RAM content... How to do this?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: As I'm the only user on computer, it's not a password hack. If I have admin rights, why can't I have access to the *whole* RAM? ("some RAM areas won't be accessible for obvious security reasons")

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE. It is the same to say that your bank account manager can see your password just because he is the manager.

Comment: It seems possible: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4641/~/collecting-a-full-memory-dump-in-windows-10

Comment: You can dump the whole memory, But you CANNOT read encrypted/protected parts of it, You'll only get junk. If that was possible It would be a major security issue.